# filtering an array of object based on string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

my problem might not be as challenging as some other similar questions but they were a little to much for me.

I have an array of objects that I need to filter by name against a string array of names, if the names match I want to remove the object with the name that matches

so like the following:

```
nameObjects = [{name: 'name3', value: 'some val'},{name: 'name1', value:'some other val'}]
names = ['name1','name2','name3']
```

I've tried the following just using for loops but I'm sure that there is a quicker (and correct lol) filter method that works

```
         for(i=0; i < this.names.length; i++){
            for(j=0; j < this.nameObjects.length; j++){

              if(this.names[i] === this.nameObjects[j].name){
                this.files.splice(i,this.nameObjects[j])
              }
            }
          }
```

also sorry for the poor logic ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not mutate the array while you are looping over it.

You can simply use `Array.prototype.filter` with `Array.prototype.includes` to get the desired result

```js
const nameObjects = [{name: 'name3', value: 'some val'},{name: 'name1', value:'some other val'}];
const names = ['name2','name3'];
const res = nameObjects.filter(obj => !names.includes(obj.name));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I see, so take the opposite, thank you this worked out perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const nameObjects = [
    { name: "name3", value: "some val" },
    { name: "name1", value: "some other val" },
];
const names = ["name1", "name2"];

const result = nameObjects.filter(obj => !names.includes(obj.name));

console.log(result);
```